# Find files containing a string and return line number & a preview of the line

Tags: linux, grep

I use this command to find all files of a given type in a given directory which that contain a given string:

```
find /path/to/dir/ -name "*.php" -exec grep -l "my string" {} \;
```

However it only returns the file names. Is it possible that it could also return all **line numbers** where matches were found and (for bonus points) **a preview** of each line? If so, would this be significantly slower?

Secondly, how could I make it work with multiple file types?

Comment: I'm going to leave this open as the "duplicate" answers do not restrict by filetype and are many hundreds of times slower than the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find /path/to/dir/ -name "*.php" -or -name "*.py" -exec awk '/my string/ { printf "%s - %s - %s\n\n",FILENAME,FNR,$0 }' '{}' +
```

Use -or with find to search multiple file types and then use awk to print the data required.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you. The multiple file types doesnt seem to work however. It returns nothing if I include `-or -name "*.py"` but works perfectly without it. Could I add line breaks to the output?

Comment: OK. I've amended the answer to add an extra line feed after each line. What version of find are you using?